# Quick check on function composition notation

Tags: functions, notation

Does $f^n(x)$ always mean $f(f(f(f(...f(x))))....)$ [n times]?
i.e. $f^3(x)$ always means $f(f(f(x)))$?
Does $f^0(x)$ mean $x$? [where $f\neq id$]

By always, I mean regardless of whether it's for proofs in computer science or for calculus.

Just want to be doubly sure so I don't make any unfounded leaps in my proofs by induction for computer science.

Apologies for this simian question.
Many thanks!

Comment: Were the answers on [this similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/8111/7850) not to your liking?

Comment: Also, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/24450/7850)

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out. They didn't come up whilst writing the question, but I should have exercised more due diligence. Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Sometimes $f^n$ refers to multiplication, rather than composition of functions. This is especially true with trigonometric functions: for example, $\sin^2(x)$ always means $\sin(x) \cdot \sin(x)$, never $\sin(\sin(x))$. Outside trigonometry, composition is a more likely meaning, but multiplication is possible.

Do not confuse either of these with $f^{(n)}$, which means the $n$th derivative of $f$.

Comment: Thanks Chris. However does $f^0(x)$ = x? Or does it also have multiple meanings?

Comment: Well, I suppose it might mean the constant function $1$. But I wasn't sure about its usage, so I left it out.