# Is there a simpler expression for $f(f(f(...f(x)...)))$ (total n '$f$')?

Tags: notation

> Is there a simpler expression for $f(f(f(...f(x)...)))$ (total n '$f$') ?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that this question was asked several times on this site: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/a-short-way-to-say-ffffx), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247710/notation-for-repeated-application-of-function) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453575/recursive-application-of-a-function-symbol-of).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation $f^n=\underset{\text{$n$-times}}{\underbrace{f\circ \dots \circ f}}$ is commonly used. (So $f(f(\dots f(x)\dots))=f^n(x)$.)

Occasionally this might be confused with $(f(x))^n$, i.e. the $n$-th power of the value $f(x)$, but it is usually clear from the context which of the two is meant.

See Wikipedia article [Iterated function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function).

Comment: Usually to avoid confusion some people write $f^{(n)}(x)$, but then again this may be used somewhere else and just shifts the confusion.

Comment: Yeah, $f^{(n)}$ is sometimes used for the $n-th$ derivative.